# Finding the binary tree height using Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

I am trying to code the binary tree height problem but the Prolog returns false instead of height value.

My code is :

```
height( nil, 0 ).
height( t(_,L, R), H ):-
   (  height(L,_)>height(R,_), height(L,H-1)
   ;  height(R,_)>=height(L,_),height(R,H-1)
   ).
```

A simple sample code that returns false instead of 1 is :

```
height(t(a,nil,nil),RES).
```

Thank you.

Comment: `>` and `>=` expect arithmetic expressions only. That should produce a clean error. And `H-1` is a term and not an expression...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`height` is not a function that returns the height. It is a `predicate` that is true when the second argument is the height of the first argument. So you can use `height(L,_) > height(R,_)`. You have to do `height(L,LH), height(R,RH)` and compare `LH` with `RH`. For similar reasons, you cannot query `height(L, H-1)` and get expected results since, as @false points out, `H-1` is the term `'-'(H,1)` in this context, and is not interpreted as an arithmetic expression. In Prolog, an arithmetic expression is only interpreted when it's on the right hand side of an `is` expression, or is in an arithmetic comparison expression.

So in full, your corrected predicate looks like:

```
height( nil, 0 ).         % Height of nil tree is 0
height( t(_,L,R), H ) :-  % Height of binary tree t(_,L,R) is H if...
   height(L, LH),         % LH is the height of subtree L, and
   height(R, RH),         % RH is the height of subtree H, and
   (  LH > RH             % if LH > RH, then
   -> H is LH + 1         %   H is LH + 1
   ;  H is RH + 1         % otherwise, H is RH + 1
   ).
```

Or more directly, you can use the `max` function available in Prolog (as @false points out):

```
height( nil, 0 ).         % Height of nil tree is 0
height( t(_,L,R), H ) :-  % Height of binary tree t(_,L,R) is H if...
   height(L, LH),         % LH is the height of subtree L, and
   height(R, RH),         % RH is the height of subtree H, and
   H is max(LH, RH) + 1.
```

Again, note here that an expression on the right hand side of the `is` will be evaluated by Prolog.

Comment: how would it be if we would like to find size of tree? Would it be sth like:

`size(nil, 0).
size(t(L,X,R) :-
  size(L, XL),
  size(R, XR),
  X is XL + XR + 1.`

Am I right or am I wrong guys?:)

Comment: @jake-ferguson that looks about right. I wouldn't call it `size` though since that's a bit vague. I'd call it `node_count`, or even better, `binary_tree_node_count`.